# Regular Expression not matching in java replaceAll() method

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string -

```
f.dollar_sales,f.unit_sales
```

I want to use String.replaceAll(regex,regex) method to get an output string as follows:

```
dollar_sales,unit_sales
```

I used the following:

```
fieldList.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]\\Q.\\E"," ");
```

where fieldList is String variable where I've stored input String.

Can someone point out where I've made a mistake?

Comment: So you are trying to replace f.dollar_sales with just dollar_sales? Right?

Comment: Will the input string always contain, `f.` before the values you want, or will it always be a `[a-z].`? Do you need regular expression for this or would a simple `substring` suffice?

Comment: this works for me.. `System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]\\Q.\\E", ""));` replace the match with an empty string not with a space.

Comment: What is the result you got? And what were you expecting?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney- No anything from a-z can come as prefix.

Comment: I am still getting  f.dollar_sales,f.unit_sales as output from Eclipse terminal.

Comment: strings are immutable in java, did you print the variable which actually stores the content at the last?

Comment: Sorry -an extremely stupid mistake - I printed value of fieldList. Instead of storing output by replaceAll method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your replaced string and `\Q` .. `\E` is not necessary here.

```
fieldList = fieldList.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]\\.", "");
```

[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/b2GO71)

Comment: Yes this is the mistake OP is making +1

Answer (score 1):

String is immutable, so you need to assign the updated string to that variable.

please run the below code;

```
public class StringReplace {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String fieldList="f.dollar_sales,f.unit_sales";
        fieldList=fieldList.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]\\Q.\\E"," ");
        System.out.println(fieldList);
    }
}
```